# How to Suppress Event calls in Blazor?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, blazor

I have a page that has a form having a TODO list with Add Button and at the footer of the form there is submit and cancel button. When I press the add button in the todolist the Submit function is being triggered. How to stop this triggering of the submit function call on clicking add button

Comment: How to help with code that you don't see? ;) Please make use of the [edit] link and give us the relevant parts of your code. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Default behaviour for an html button in an html form is to submit.

To prevent this add `type=button` to your button.